# Azure Devops hosted build getting and deploying old files

Tags: git, build, azure-devops

A build / release pipeline combo is deploying the appsettings.json files (all the environment ones etc) from a commit that has been superseded multiple times. This is in a hosted build for an environment that we remove on a weekly basis and appears to be getting the old files on each build/release.

This had been working fine for quite a while before this behaviour started, we've tried deleting the files in source control, changing the file contents, creating a new appsettings file suite with the same names, all of which result in these old files being deployed. We rebuild the environment from scratch as we need it, which means these aren't old files on the server that can't be overwritten.

I'm wondering if we've somehow marked these files in a way that the build will only ever get these versions, is this possible? Any other ideas?

Cheers

Comment: What are you using for source control? Git or TFVC? Is your build set to clean? Have you tried putting an inline script in your pipeline to print out the file contents to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is a git SC solution (tagged it but forgot to put it in the body sorry). I think clean has been deprecated from the build pipeline, I'll have a look at putting a script in to help diagnose, but I can't help but feel it must be getting the old versions as when we deploy to a new environment they still show up. Cheers

Comment: We are also experiencing this not always weird behavior of Azure Devops. Have you found any cause?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not exactly the way you implemented the deployment.

It is actually picking up the default version of the file that has been cached at the DevOps Agent's server location.

First of all, did you also change the agent?
If not then, all you need to do is restart the agent (First approach).

The second approach would be to look exactly how you have implemented the solution. Are you using any tokenization in your solution?

If not then you should definitely go for them!